# run a containerised vault instance without initialising

Tags: docker, docker-compose, initialization, containers, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to start a containerised vault instance (from hashicorp) without initialising the vault itself (so no root token or unseal key are generated). This is a harder challenge than initially thought since, as soon as the container starts, the vault automatically initialises.

My docker-compose.yml looks as follows:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  vault:
    image: vault:1.8.0
    container_name: my_vault
    ports:
      - "7442:8200"
    volumes:
      - "./config:/vault/config"
      - "./data:/vault/data"
    cap_add:
      - "IPC_LOCK"
    restart: always
```

The `vault/config` folder contains a single file called `vault-config.json` which contains the following:

```json
{
  "default_lease_ttl": "168h",
  "max_lease_ttl": "720h"
}
```

Why does it keep initialising as soon as I start the container? There's no reason for it, right?

Comment: how have you built the container? do you have an entrypoint thats starting it

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I just use `docker-compose up -d` on the `docker-compose.yml` above. Nothing else

Comment: yeah but i mean on your vault container? whats its entrypoint script? generally when you start a container it will run an entrypoint script or a command.

Answer (score 0):

What Vault does when it initializes is create/format the storage its given. The storage was probably initialized at some point and stayed that way ever since.

To have Vault start uninitialized every time, delete the `data` directory before starting the container. This should do the trick:

```
rm -Rf ./data
mkdir ./data
docker-compose up --detach
```